# Cannot store Get-aduser value to variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am unable to Store value of Get-aduser -filter * into a variable below is the code, $a shows blank.

```
$a=Get-ADUser -filter * | Select samaccountname, mail, surname, givenname,LastLogondate
```

This one works fine for single object:

```
$a=Get-ADUser -identity 'name' | Select samaccountname, mail, surname, givenname,LastLogondate
```

But i want for All users, is there an alternate way to handle this request.?

Comment: Is `$a` the actual variable name you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet :(

the code

```
$a=Get-ADUser -filter * | Select samaccountname, mail, surname, givenname,LastLogondate
```

is correct and works fine for me, what happens if you run normally without the variable?

as an answer you could try

```
$a=Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Select samaccountname, mail, surname, givenname,LastLogondate | ft
```

Comment: Without variable, output is displayed fine. suggested one didn't work as well.

Comment: what happen if you try a different variable name, it could be related to this http://superuser.com/questions/777416/why-does-the-powershell-ise-not-isolate-script-variables-to-the-script-scope

Comment: tried different variables as well. I am looking into new way to process it, since i am able to export the data to txt file with Samaccount name, then get the content of the samaccount into differnt variable and loop through Get-aduser.

Comment: Get-ADUser -filter * -property name | select samaccountname -ExpandProperty samaccountname|out-file c:\aduser.txt -Append

$usersname=get-content c:\aduser.txt

Comment: maybe if you specify all properties explicitly?
`$a=Get-ADUser -filter * -properties samaccountname, mail, surname, givenname,LastLogondate  | Select samaccountname, mail, surname, givenname,LastLogondate `

Answer (score 0):

Well I was Still not able store -filter output in a variable. Hence went another way round of exporting to text file and then get the text file info into foreach loop to perform further activity, below part of code might help someone, don't forget to remove the aduser.txt after each run, will look into better solution sometime later:

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -property name | select samaccountname -ExpandProperty samaccountname|out-file c:\aduser.txt -Append
 $usersname=""  
 $usersname=get-content c:\aduser.txt
 $usersname.count
 $vmarray=""
 $vmarray=@()
 foreach ($item in $usersname)

 {
    $list=""
        $list=get-aduser -Identity $item -property mail, surname, givenname, LastLogondate,memberof| Select samaccountname, mail, surname, givenname,LastLogondate,memberof
        $member=get-aduser -Identity $item -property memberof| Select memberof -ExpandProperty memberof

                $mem=""
                $ou=""
                foreach ($mem in $member)
                {
                $ou= ($mem.memberof).replace("OU=","")
            }



            $obj= new-object psobject -Property @{
            EmailId=$list.mail
            SurName=$list.surname
            FirstName=$list.givenname
            lastlogon=$list.LastLogondate
            Adid=$list.samaccountname
            FullmembershipOU=$ou
            InfoRecordedON=$date
            }
            $vmarray+=$obj
            }



 $vmarray.count
 $vmarray|ft
```